# Target google calendar when using jwt access

Tags: node.js, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I use [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) to access my calendar on server side application. My app's user is only for me, so I use jwt access via service account.

After setting up a service account on [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project), I could get/insert events to calendar via google api library. But I couldn't find any events in Google calendar on web browser. Of course I use a same google account for setting service account on developers console and checking google calendar web app.

Perhaps if I use a service account, is a special calendar created? Is it possible to get/insert events from/into my existing calendar via calendar id? I got an error when I set existing calendar id to get events, 'Not found'. I could only set 'primary' as a calendar_id.

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer by myself. If I use existing calendars, I have to set 'sharing settings' to each calendar in google calendar.

1. Open google calendar
2. Go to calendar setting page
3. Open 'share setting' that calendar you want to use
4. add your service account email (xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com) and set authorization level.

Then, I could access existing calendars!